# BackgroundWorker reports progress faster than the "progress" UI can update itself

Tags: winforms, backgroundworker

I have a Windows Forms app that uses a `BackgroundWorker` component to run a number of SQL commands, read from a script. The number of commands and their performance can vary greatly, so I can't predict how long each command will take.

Every time it finishes a command, it reports statistics to the UI using a `ProgressChanged` event. It then updates three different parts of the screen, while a timer component updates another part of the screen every 2 seconds to alert the user to total time elapsed (and show that the app isn't frozen.)

If each command takes a reasonably long time (half a second or more), everything works fine.

The problem is that sometimes each command takes only a few hundredths of a second, and the UI update for that step takes longer than that. So the next UI update event will fire before the previous one has been completely handled.

When that happens, the screen updates appear to queue up, updating one portion of the screen over and over again (with new data), not updating the other 2 portions of the screen, and not allowing interaction with the rest of the app.

So I wind up with a "frozen in place" app until all those updates are done, almost as if I were running the commands on the UI thread!

Now, it may well be that there are faster ways to update the screen: I'm looking into that (I didn't write the original program.)

But the general problem is that the screen update can be slower than each reportable step taken by the `BackgroundWorker`, and the UI update work ... backs up.

Is there an architecture pattern I can use to avoid this? Something involving queues, and another worker thread, perhaps? It is OK with me if the command scripts finish before the UI updates finish, as long as all 3 parts of the screen are updated for a given event before the next event gets handled.

What I have tried:

1. Sprinkling `DoEvents` throughout the UI update. This keeps everything from being locked solid, but leads to StackOverflowExceptions due to new events being handled before the old ones are done.
2. Research. I have read about `BackgroundWorkers` and multithreading. But I think what I'm dealing with is a different kind of synchronization, and possibly an architecture question: I haven't found anything to address the specific case of "the UI update can (but doesn't always) take longer than each background work step"!

Comment: Yes, that happens.  Basic workarounds are to call ReportProgress less often, collecting intermediate results in a List.  And to re-think the user interface, nobody is actually going to read all that info.

Comment: You could handle a Queue of actions that are used to update the UI. For example, when you call `BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> [Action]))` you add your method to a queue that is handled internally. Then `PostMessage()` executes it *asynchronously*. The same way, you can enqueue actions that are perfected at your own pace

Comment: @Jimi Could you provide an example? Or refer me to one? I've read about BeginInvoke as part of asynchronous handling, but haven't ever coded it from scratch!

Comment: First, get rid of `BackgroundWorker`, https://halfblood.pro/how-to-replace-backgroundworker-with-async-await-and-tasks-80d7c8ed89dc Second, only use that 2-second timer to update UI, so that any background data changes can be cached in the memory and write to UI only when the timer expires.

Comment: If any of you would like to write your response up as an answer, I'll select it as "accepted".